# code signing windows software: just the installer, or also the main app itself?

Tags: installation, executable, code-signing

I'm currently in the process of code-signing my software, to avoid the infamous 'Unknown Publisher' warning popup. I noticed this warning typically only appears when running the installer. Once the software is installed, running the application itself doesn't cause this warning to pop up again.

Question: should I code-sign only my installer, or is there any point in code-signing the application itself as well? (i.e. the executable that is installed by the installer)

I guess it couldn't hurt to just sign everything, but are there any actual pros or cons I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

You should always sign all your binaries. Otherwise, unsigned file may me become the target of antivirus program. Some firewalls may forbid internet access for the unsigned application. Also, it's simply a good form of software development.

Any cons? I don't think so. Binaries size may increase a little, but that should stop you from signing.

Also, if you use some unsigned third-party libraries - you shouldn't sign them (as far as I know). Maybe it is somehow described in the library's licensing document.

Comment: Also, signature ensures that the file has not been modified by third-party. You as a developer (or a company) take responsibility for quality of service.